# Custom metadata from .nd2 files

Tags: python, image, import

I have a series of `.nd2` files from NIS Elements AR, associated with Nikon microscopes. In Elements AR custom user defined metadata can be added to images/image series and is saved in the `.nd2` format. When these files are saved and then reopened in Elements AR the custom metadata is all displayed correctly

A range of python `.nd2` importers exists eg. `nd2`, `nd2reader` and `pims_nd2`. However although these packages can extract most of the `.nd2` metadata I cannot access the user defined custom metadata. Perhaps I am missing a function in these packages to access the user defined metadata (the `.custom_data` option in `nd2` does not work)

Does anyone have any experience extracting this type of custom metadata from Nikon `.nd2` files or similar proprietary microscope software?

Comment: Author of nd2 here, it would be great if you could open an issue with the file at the GitHub repo.  Happy to make sure you can extract whatever you need from the metadata if it’s not already working for you.  Also, there have been a lot of recent updates, so you might just try it again?

Answer (score 1):

One work around is using an ImageJ macro to open and save metadata as txt files and then extract that data using a language like python.

This code works:

```
import nd2
f = nd2.ND2File('nd2_image_path') # load image
all_metadata = f.unstructured_metadata() # Load all metadata as a dict
x_pos = all_metadata['ImageMetadataSeqLV|0']['SLxPictureMetadata']['XPos'] # Find x coordinate
y_pos = all_metadata['ImageMetadataSeqLV|0']['SLxPictureMetadata']['YPos'] # Find y coordinate
```